# Javascript sorting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm working on a livescores application using tables rows to display the records. The sorting is done by tr class name which has a value created by dateTime+countryId+leagueId+matchId, so the class becomes something like 1349565600312117160466446000000000000000 (i'm adding some zeros at the end to make all numbers having the same length).

The problem (with or without the zeros) is that the number is too big to be used for sorting with javascript so i was wondeing if there's a way to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the numbers are of the same length, Use the techniques of sorting strings.It will convert this number into characters and sort them according to ASCII value.

```
$(function(){    
    var strings = [];
    strings.push(your_value); // your_value like 1349565600312117160466446000000000000000
    strings.sort();
});
```

Insert as much value as you need into string array and the `strings.sort()` will sort them !

Comment: can you give an example of this method?

Answer (score 0):

If all the numbers have the same length, then you can just sort them as strings.

Note that you might run into some trouble if your fields aren't all the same length (e.g. two-digit vs. one-digit country IDs). In that case you may want to zero-pad all of your values before they get packed into the classname, or just join the values with some non-numeric character and sort arrays of split numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you could have 2 functions :

1. one to split this number into individual items just like you mentioned
2. one to recreate them.

on page load, call the function that will go through all the items in the DOM, and populate an array ,make the sort there, and the re-iterate the array to create the new DOM order